# How can I get fragment by tag?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I've found a lot of questions about that, but none of these can help me.

I have a "MainActivity" which have 4 fragments.

I need to access to one of these fragments, called "my_fragment", in an other simple activity, let's call "SecondActivity".

So, I try to put a property android:tag="my_fragment" in the LinearLayout markup XML of "my_fragment".
And after that, I do that in "SecondActivity":

Fragment frg  = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("my_fragment");

... in order to get my fragment. But frg is always null.

I try a lot of others ways, but in vain. This one seems better and easier to do, but perhaps I'm wrong.

Any help would be appreciate. Thank you in advance.

Fabien

**EDIT**

Since your answers that indicate that's isn't possible, I want to specify what I need.
I just want to get this fragment for reload it. I found something like that on an other subject on Stackoverflow:

```
    frg= getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(my_fragment);
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.detach(frg);
    ft.attach(frg);
    ft.commit();
```

By the way, I just try to get the fragment in the fragment himself and it's still return null. With the method :

```
findFragmentById(R.layout.my_fragment)
```

it's the same result.

And after, I did :

```
findFragmentById(this.getId())
```

But it's make an infinite looper, I don't understand the reason...

**EDIT2**

Alright, let’s give some details :

I have MainActivity with ViewPager with 4 fragments. It’s not fragments at the xml sense. Sorry if I’m confused, I was training to Android very recently and somethings are not clear for me again. So, before yesterday and the read of @Bruce edit, I was thinking that fragments were the components of a ViewPager. So, @Bruce, this is why I can’t use your solution. I was trying to use findFragmentByTag with the tag applicate on my principal LinearLayout markup of my fragment - that is not, I repeat, an xml markup fragment.

This is my approach :
In my MainActivity, I click on the third fragment. I make a research for find some points around me. After an action of the user, still from the third fragment, I open the SecondActivity for authentification and on the user connection, I close this SecondActivity. Now, I need to reload the fourth fragment that will adapt his components in terms of the user situation, while keeping the same state on the third fragment, with points loaded. It’s why can’t use your solution @menion.asamm : I can’t reinstantiate the MainActivity, even if I simulate a click on the third fragment because it will come back in his initial state, without points loaded.

Thank you both of you @Bruce and @menion.asamm for your time in helping me !

Comment: Hello, if I understand correctly, you tries to access Fragment attached to first activity, in your second activity? I'm worried, this is not possible. I suggest to think, if there is any alternative solution or you may share reason why you wants to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Fragments are always owned by one activity, so you cannot directly access a different activity's fragments. The call you are making is looking for fragments within your SecondActivity.

Why do you want to do this? Once some UI is off screen (MainActivity), you usually don't want to do anything with those UI objects, because Android may have removed them from memory. If there is data in "my_fragment" that is needed by SecondActivity, one approach might be to save the data in SharedPreferences or a database in my_fragment, and then load it in SecondActivity.

EDIT
I'm not sure you're getting that it is important which activity you are running in. Here are two options for how to proceed:

1. If you just want to run the SAME instance of your fragment that was already running inside MainActivity, then maybe what you want to do is finish your SecondActivity to return to MainActivity.
2. If you want a NEW copy of the same fragment inside SecondActivity, then you can include the fragment inside SecondActivity's layout (or add it to some container later).

Also, notice that for your call to findFragmentById, the ID needs to be the ID that was specified in the layout file as the value of android:id (not the R.layout.my_fragment). It might be better to use a fragment tag, which you can either specify in your layout file or when you add the fragment.

Mainly I think you need to read Google's guide on fragments.

EDIT2:
Ah, I see, I have a similar fragment-refresh situation in my app. You basically need to get data from SecondActivity back to the fragment inside MainActivity. The approach I use is this:

1. Save the data from SecondActivity in storage (DB or SharedPreferences).
2. Finish SecondActivity so that MainActivity and your fragment are shown again.
3. Override onResume in your fragment to fetch the data you saved in SecondActivity.

Another option is to launch SecondActivity using startActivityForResult, and then process the results in MainActivity, passing them to its fragment.

Regarding how to find the fragment by tag, you first need to set the fragment's tag. If you are declaring your fragment in a layout XML, then you can do it there (and you can also declare

```
<fragment class="com.xyz.MyFragment"
    android:tag="MyFragment"
    android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Now from inside MainActivity you can either do `findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment)` or `findFragmentByTag("MyFragment")`.

If you are NOT declaring the fragment in XML, but adding it directly, you can set the fragment's tag as part of the add call:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.frag_parent, new MyFragment(), tag);
```

EDIT3: Ah, you're using ViewPager to hold fragments. Now I understand better. They're still fragments, but getting access to them is indeed tricky, because Android constructs a fragment tag in some internal code. Here is another SO question on this issue:
[Retrieve a Fragment from a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager)

Comment: Thank you for your edit. I want to refresh a fragment because his content is updating according to datas which are set in the SecondActivity. Also, findFragmentById needs an int parameter so, how can I proceed with the value of android:id ?

Comment: Ok, I understand why I can’t find the fragment. It’s because it’s not a fragment. I explain the situation in details, I edited my ask.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm if you really need just refresh of fragment attached to different activity, I suggest:

- first activity start second activity with

  ```
  startActivityForResult(intent, MY_CODE);
  ```
- second activity when wants to refresh fragment in first activity, finish it's state with

  ```
  Intent data = new Intent();
  data.putExtra("REFRESH_FRAGMENT", true);
  setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
  finish();
  ```
- back in first activity, you may catch this result by

  ```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      // check request code
      if (requestCode == MY_CODE) {
          // check result
          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
              // check data
              if (data != null && data.getBooleanExtra("REFRESH_FRAGMENT", false)) {
                  refreshFragment();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Possible?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, it's seems realizable. But something escape me : what's the method refreshFragment() ?

Comment: It should be whatever you need. You previously wrote you need to reload your fragment. So do it here. In moment you execute some "refreshFragment" function, you are already in activity where you may obtain fragment by it's tag.

Comment: I can’t do that. Because I don’t want to re-instantiate my MainActivity otherwhise, it will re-init it. I explain the situation in details, I edited my ask.

Comment: @Fabien: Read the answer carefully - there is no reinitialization of the `Activity`.